# File should upload outside the root folder

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload

Im using codeigniter framework,
I have two folders in my public html folder,one contains the main website and other have mobile website
Both having same database

The issue that im facing is, 
i want to upload a file  from mobile website which should be uploaded in the folder which can be accessible for both sites(mobile and main).
While uploading from mobile site ,it only uploading inside the mobile folder(mobile site)
Some one please tell me how can i upload the file outside the mobile folder(mobile web root),im really struggling in it.
Fileshould upload outside the root folder

Give below is the code i am using

```
if($_FILES["resumecar"]["name"]){
$file = basename($_FILES['resumecar']['name']);
$ext = end(explode('.', $file));
$ext = strtolower($ext);
$filename = "resume_".time().'.'.$ext;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["resumecar"]["tmp_name"],"uploads/careers/".$filename);
$uploadfile = "uploads/careers/".$filename;

}else{$filename = '';}
```

Comment: can you post your existing code that is doing the upload?

Comment: Well, if it's any help, there's nothing inherent in CodeIgniter that should prevent you from doing that. Create a folder somewhere safe, set permissions, and use that path on both versions. Alternately you could use symlinks in each site-specific folder that point to a common folder elsewhere.

Comment: this is the code i am using                  if($_FILES["resumecar"]["name"]){
$file = basename($_FILES['resumecar']['name']);
$ext = end(explode('.', $file));
$ext = strtolower($ext);
$filename = "resume_".time().'.'.$ext;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["resumecar"]["tmp_name"],  "uploads/careers/".$filename);
$uploadfile = "uploads/careers/".$filename;

}else{$filename = '';}